# JQuery each loop works not as expected when there's an if clause in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, each

I'm working on my custom autocomplete plugin that compares user input against data in json file

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#user_input").keyup(function() {
      var input = $("#user_input").val();
      var templ = new RegExp('^' + input, 'i');

      $.getJSON("json/test.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
          console.log(this['name']);
        })
      })
    })
  })
</script>
```

When the code is represented in this form I get all the values displayed in the console. This is fine. However, when I want to provide a condition inside my **$.each** statement like this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#user_input").keyup(function() {
      var input = $("#user_input").val();
      var templ = new RegExp('^' + input, 'i');

      $.getJSON("json/test.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function() {
          if (templ.test(this['name'])) {
            console.log(this['name']);
          }
        })
      })
    })
  })

</script>
```

I get matching elements displaying in console twice as if the **$.each** is executed 2 times. How can I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: Do u want to break your loop if IF condition is true?

Comment: No, I want to console.log all the elements that match regexp

Comment: Put a console, above the getJson line and check if keyup is getting called twice?

Comment: It is not... in my first script without an if clause $.each executes once. The problem is due to an if clause, but I don't know what it actually is

Comment: how is the "data" structured? just a usual json like key:value?